# Antisymmetrization of the electronic wave function

Tags: wavefunction, symmetry, resource-recommendations, fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle

I'm studying systems of many electrons (for Theoretical Quantum Chemistry) from Landau, Quantum Mechanics (non-relativistic theory), chapters 61, 62, and 63.

I wanted to ask for good references to study systems of many identical particles (with a specific focus on electrons) that provide a detailed explanation of the wave function's permutations, symmetrization, and antisymmetrization of the wave function and how to perform it using Young diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

I dunno know if it’s sufficiently modern but try

> Harvey, Malcolm. The symmetric group and its relevance to fermion physics. No. AECL-7166. CM-P00067619, 1981

available [from Cern here](https://cds.cern.ch/record/135395/files/CM-P00067619.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much. Well, for sure better than nothing, but I will still wait to close the answer to see if any other source is available.

Comment: actually it's really well done.  The more modern developments are oriented towards computer applications but from a theory perspective this is quite nice.